# Как перенести сайт на другой движок без вреда seo

Tags: .htaccess, seo, миграция

Как настроить редиректы со всех старых ссылок на новые чтоб не терять трафик из поиска по старым ссылам при переносе сайта с одного движка на другой и со сменой старых ссылок на более seo оптиимизированые?Нужно ли что то настраивать в гугл вебмастере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создать такие же ЧПУ как на старом сайте

и/или

2. Настроить 301 редирект

Comment: спасибо. Редирект одной страницы на другую страницу:

Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.site.com/newpage.html